# A clock for 2017

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Design a clock where each number from 1 to 12 is obtained as an arithmetical operation using each digit of 2017 exactly once: for example,  4 could be made as $2\times 7-10$.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was going to be [this clock](https://xkcd.com/1655/)

Comment: "tick" means checkmark. It took me a while to figure out what it meant because this question is about clocks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With the digits in order:

$$
\begin{align}
1 &= 2 + 0 - 1 ^ 7 \\
2 &= 2 + 0 \times 1 \times 7 \\
3 &= 2 + 0 + 1 ^ 7 \\
4 &= -2 - 0 - 1 + 7 \\
5 &= 2 \times (0 - 1) + 7 \\
6 &= 2 \times 0 - 1 + 7\\
7 &= 2 \times 0 \times 1 + 7 \\
8 &= 2 \times 0 + 1 + 7 \\
9 &= 2 + 0 \times 1 + 7 \\
10 &= 2 + 0 + 1 + 7 \\
11 &= 2 + 0! + 1 + 7 \\
12 &= 2 \times (0 - 1 + 7) \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment:  my applauds...

Comment: 4 feels like a bit of a cheat to me though :(

Comment: To avoid using the negative on 4 you could do 2+0!+1^7 :)

Comment: really impressive!

Answer (score 48):

I tried to make a digital clock.

$0 = (7 + 1 + 2) \times 0$
$1 = (2 + 7 + 1) ^ 0$
$2 = (7 + 1) \times 0 + 2$
$3 = 7 \times 0 + 2 + 1$
$4 = 2 \times 7 - 10$
$5 = 7 - 2 + 1 \times 0$
$6 = 7 - 1 + 2 \times 0$
$7 = 7 + 1 * 2 \times 0$
$8 = 7 + 1 + 0 \times 2$
$9 = 7 + 2 + 1 \times 0$
$10 = 1 + 2 + 7 + 0$
$11 = 12 - 7^0$
$12 = 12 + 7 \times 0$
$13 = 12 + 7 ^ 0$
$14 = 7 \times 2 + 1 \times 0$
$15 = 7 \times 2 + 1 + 0$
$16 = (7 + 1) \times 2 + 0$
$17 = (7 + 1) \times 2 + 0!$
$18 = (7 + 2) \times (1 + 0!)$
$19 = 10 + 2 + 7$
$20 = 17 + 2 + 0!$
$21 = 7 \times (2 + 1 + 0)$
$22 = 7 \times (2 + 1) + 0!$
$23 = 17 + (2 + 0!)!$  or $(7-2-1)! - 0!$  thanks to stack reader
$24 = 2 \times 7 + 10$

[Edit]
What the hell...lets do it for minutes also (I cheated a bit):

$25 = (7 - 1 - 0!)^2$
$26 = 27 - 1 + 0$
$27 = 27 + 1 \times 0$
$28 = 27 + 1 + 0$
$29 = 27 + 1 + 0!$
$30 = 10 \times \lfloor\frac{7}{2}\rfloor$
$31 = \lceil\log(17!) \times 2\rceil + 0!$  // $\log(17!) = 14.5510$
$32 = (1+0!)^{(7-2)}$
$33 = 17 \times 2 - 0!$
$34 = 17 \times 2 + 0$
$35 = 17 \times 2 + 0!$
$36 = \frac{70}{2} + 1$
$37 = \lfloor\ln {7}^{20}\rfloor - 1$ // $\ln {7}^{20} = (38.9182)$
$38 = \lfloor\ln {7}^{20}\rfloor \times 1$ // $\ln {7}^{20} = (38.9182)$
$39 = \lfloor\ln {7}^{20}\rfloor + 1$ // $\ln {7}^{20} = (38.9182)$
$40 = 10 \times \lceil\frac{7}{2}\rceil$
$41 = \lceil\ln {7}^{21}\rceil + 0 $ // $\ln {7}^{21} = (40.8641)$
$42 = \lfloor\ln {72}^{10}\rfloor$ // $\ln {72}^{10} = (42.76666)$
$43 = \lceil\ln {72}^{10}\rceil$ // $\ln {72}^{10} = (42.76666)$
$44 = \lceil{(\ln 710})^{2}\rceil$ // $({\ln 710})^{2} = (43.1027)$
$45 = \lfloor\log(10!) * 7 - \ln(2)\rfloor $  // $\log(10!) = 6.5597$
$46 = \lceil\log(10!) * 7 - \ln(2)\rceil $  // $\log(10!) = 6.5597$
$47 = 7^2 - 1 - 0!$
$48 = 7^2 - 1 + 0$
$49 = 7^2 + 1 \times 0$
$50 = 7^2 + 1 + 0$
$51 = 7^2 + 1 + 0!$
$52 = \lceil\log(2^{170})\rceil$ // $\log(2^{170}) = (51.1750)$
$53 = \lfloor\ln(17!)\rfloor + 20$ // $\ln(17!) = 33.5050$
$54 = 27 \times (1 + 0!)$
$55 = \lceil\ln(27!)\rceil - 10$ // $\ln(27!) = 64.5575$
$56 = \lfloor\ln(17^{20})\rfloor $  // $\ln(17^{20}) = 56.6642 $
$57 = \lceil\ln(17^{20})\rceil $  // $\ln(17^{20}) = 56.6642 $
$58 = 70 - 12 $
$59 = 7^2 + 10$

Comment: @oleslaw....there was no need for 24, because I got 0, but thanks. :)

Comment: (7-2-1)! - 0! = 23

Comment: @stackreader. Thanks. I found an other one in the meantime.

Comment: @Marius Oh, you're right. You can delete it or leave it as you want :P

Comment: Neh...I'l leave it. I've seen screwed up digital clocks in my life :)

Comment: You could avoid some logarithms and roundings by using binomial coefficients (which you can write using only parentheses). For example 38=binomial(10,2)-7 ; 42=binomial(7,2)*(1+0!) ; 52=binomial(10,2)+7 ; 56=binomial(7+1,2+0!). Some other method would probably be needed to get rid of all of them, though

Comment: @Leo I can't argue with that, but I'm not doing all the numbers again.

Comment: You could do $37 = 20 + 17$ ;-)

Comment: yeah, I could, but I got in to the rhythm with the math functions that I forgot about the "normal" stuff. Check the edit history to see the last 2 numbers I filled in. Not what you would expect.

Answer (score 11):

> $1 = 7 \times 0 + 2 - 1$
>
>  $2 = 7 \times 0 + 2 \times 1$
>
>  $3 = 20 - 17$
>
>  $4 = 7 - 2 - 1 - 0$
>
>  $5 = 7 - 2 - 0 \times 1$
>
>  $6 = 7 - 1 - 0 \times 2$
>
>  $7 = 0 \times 1 \times 2 + 7$
>
>  $8 = 0 \times 2 + 1 + 7$
>
>  $9 = 0 \times 1 + 2 + 7$
>
>  $10 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 7$
>
>  $11 = 12 - 7 ^ 0$
>
>  $12 = 0 \times 7 + 12$

I'm assuming I'm not allowed to use ^, so give me a few minutes to find an acceptable solution for 11!

Comment: Drat! I got ninjaed...

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper I believe there is no solution for 11 using only the +, -, * and / operators (checked with brute-force computer program)

Comment: @oleslaw I'd figured just about that much. Especially when you realise the 0 is basically useless for 11.

Answer (score 4):

> $1 = 2*0*7+1$
>
>  $2 = 2+0*1*7$
>
>  $3 = 2+0*7+1$
>
>  $4 = (7+1+0)/2$
>
>  $5 = -2+0*1+7$
>
>  $6 = -2+0+1+7$
>
>  $7 = 2*0*1+7$
>
>  $8 = 2*0+1+7$
>
>  $9 = 2+0*1+7$
>
>  $10 = 2+0+1+7$
>
>  $11 = 12-7^0$
>
>  $12 = 12-7*0$

Comment: Yup, 12-7^0=11 not 12.

Comment: Yeah, my bad... I saw 12=12-7^0

Answer (score 3):

> 1=2*7*0+1
>  2=1*0*7+2
>  3=7*0+(2+1)
>  4=2*7-10
>  5=1*0+(7-2)
>  6=2*0+(7-1)
>  7=2*0*1+7
>  8=2*0+(7+1)
>  9=1*0+(7+2)
>  10=0+7+2+1
>  11=12-7^0
>  12=0*7+12

Answer (score 3):

A couple more for $12$:

> $12=20-1-7, 12=(2+0)\times(-1+7)$

Answer (score 2):

Just for entertainment value, if we limit ourselves with just 4 basic operations (+-*/) without even unary minus, *and* if we agree to use four separate digits 2,0,1,7 without combining them into numbers like 12, we still can get 11 results out of 12!

Here is the C# code:

```
var found = new Tuple<int[],Tuple<Func<Decimal, Decimal, Decimal>,string>[]>[12];
var number = new[] { 2, 0, 1, 7 };
var op = new Tuple<Func<Decimal, Decimal, Decimal>, string>[] 
{
    new Tuple<Func<Decimal, Decimal, Decimal>, string>((x,y) => x + y,"+"), 
    new Tuple<Func<Decimal, Decimal, Decimal>, string>((x,y) => x - y,"-"),
    new Tuple<Func<Decimal, Decimal, Decimal>, string>((x,y) => x * y,"*"), 
    new Tuple<Func<Decimal, Decimal, Decimal>, string>((x,y) => x / y,"/"),
};
foreach (var i in GetPermutations(number, 4))
{
    foreach (var j in GetPermutationsWithRept(op, 3))
    {
        var ii = i.ToArray(); var jj = j.ToArray();
        decimal result = ii[0]; var divideByZero = false;
        for (int k = 0;k < 3; k++)
        {
            if (jj[k] == op[3] && ii[k + 1] == 0)
            {
                divideByZero = true;
                break;
            }
            result = jj[k].Item1(result,ii[k+1]);
        }
        if (divideByZero) continue;
        if (result <= 12 && result >=1 && result == ((decimal)(int)result))
        {
            found[(int)result-1] = new Tuple<int[],Tuple<Func<Decimal, Decimal, Decimal>,string>[]>(ii,jj);
        }
    }
}
PrintResult(found);
```

And here is the result:

> 1=(((7*0)-1)+2)
>   2=(((7/1)*0)+2)
>   3=(((7-1)-0)/2)
>   4=(((7-1)-0)-2)
>   5=(((7/1)-0)-2)
>   6=(((7+1)-0)-2)
>   7=(((1*0)/2)+7)
>   8=(((7-1)-0)+2)
>   9=(((7/1)-0)+2)
>   10=(((7+1)-0)+2)
>   11=Unknown
>   12=(((7-1)-0)*2)

Implementation of `GetPermutations`, `GetPermutationsWithRept` and `PrintResult` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Anyone would like to write up a code-golf challenge for finding the clock faces ;)?

Comment: As a side note the dreadful `Tuple`s look much nicer in C# 7.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 = **1** + 0 * 2 * 7
>
> 2 = **2** + 0 * 1 * 7
>
> 3 = **1** + **2** + 0 * 7
>
> 4 = **7** - (0 + **1** + **2**)
>
> 5 = **7** - **2** + 0 * 1
>
> 6 = **7** - **1** + 0 * 2
>
> 7 = **7** + 0 * 1 * 2
>
> 8 = **7** + **1** + 0 * 2
>
> 9 = **7** + **2** + 0 * 1
>
> 10 = **7** + 0 + **1** + **2**
>
> 11 = **71** % **20**
>
> 12 = **12** + 0 * 7

, where % is a modulus operator.

Comment: why are some digits bold?

Comment: @Marius Why are all the other numbers afraid of 7? Because 7 8 9 (eight is a homophone of ate). So 7 must be bold. Or it could be that Bhaskar highlighted the numbers which contribute to the final number, so 0 * 2 * 7 does not.

Comment: @Marius looks like non-zero terms are bold

Comment: @Marius : As Andrew and wilson say, I highlighted the non-zero terms that contribute to the final results. I thought it would help in reading it quicker. Nvm if it didnt. :)

Answer (score 0):

$1 = 1 ^ {720}$

$2 = 2^0 + 1^7
$

$3 = 2^1 + 7^0$

$4 = 7 - 2 - 1 - 0$

$5 = 7 - 2^1 + 0$

$6 = (2 + 1)! + (7 × 0)$

$7 = 7 + ((2 + 1) × 0)$

$8 = 2 + 0 - 1 + 7$

$9 = 7 + 2 + (1 × 0)$

$10 = 2 + 0 + 1 + 7$

$11 = 2 + 0! + 1 + 7$

$12 = (7 + (2 + 1)!) - 0! $